# Convert Excel 'Download PDF file from webpage' code for Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, download

The Excel code below is designed to go to a webpage, search a hyperlink and download PDF file under it and save it on desktop.

I need to amend it for Outlook:

1. So that it detects a Sender email, e.g. generic@gmail.com
2. Detect the hyperlink in the email and on the webpage to detect a button 'Export Details' and press it
3. Then on next page press 'Export' button and save CVS file on Desktop: "C:\Users\mlad1406\Desktop\Test".

```vb
Sub DownPDF()
' This macro downloads the pdf file from webpage
' Need to download MSXML2 and MSHTML parsers and install

Dim sUrl As String
Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim hAnchor As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement
Dim Ret As Long
Dim sPath As String
Dim i As Long

sPath = "C:\Users\mlad1406\Desktop\Test"
sUrl = "https://copernicus.my.salesforce.com/00O20000006WD95"

'Get the directory listing
Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
xHttp.Open "GET", sUrl
xHttp.Send

'Wait for the page to load
Do Until xHttp.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'Put the page in an HTML document
Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
hDoc.Body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText

'Loop through the hyperlinks on the directory listing
For i = 0 To hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a").Length - 1
    Set hAnchor = hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a").Item(i)

    'test the pathname to see if it matches your pattern
    If hAnchor.PathName Like "Ordin-*.2013.pdf" Then
        Ret = UrlDownloadToFile(0, sUrl & hAnchor.PathName, sPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            Debug.Print sUrl & hAnchor.PathName & " downloaded to " & sPath
        Else
            Debug.Print sUrl & hAnchor.PathName & " not downloaded"
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: So you have nothing on the matter that you want to work on, ok np. But **in what do you want to detect sender mail**? By press a button, do you mean open hyperlink?

Comment: Hi there, I was thinking to detect it in the FROM: field where the email address is listed. Regarding second question: the email has a Hyperlink that needs to be detected and pressed, that will open a webpage and from there on are buttons everywhere.

Comment: Ok so you can use the code that I gave in my answer with the `oMailItem.SenderEmailAddress` and look for your link into the body. Then you will probably have to work with HTML doc to find your buttons and their respective links.

Comment: If problem solved, please validate answer to mark your question as solved. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code, that should help you to start (if you do look in mails to find the sender address) :

The field you are looking for is : `oMailItem.SenderEmailAddress`

```
Sub Extract_Body_Subject_From_Mails()

Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oFld As Outlook.Folder
Dim oMails As Outlook.Items
Dim oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oProp As Outlook.PropertyPage

Dim sSubject As String
Dim sBody

'On Error GoTo Err_OL

Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFld = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set oMails = oFld.Items

For Each oMailItem In oMails
    MsgBox oMailItem.SenderEmailAddress
        'MsgBox oMails.Count    'oMails.Item(omails.Find(
        sBody = oMailItem.Body
        sSubject = oMailItem.Subject
        'MsgBox sSubject
        MsgBox sBody      
Next

Exit Sub
Err_OL:
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub









'First create a rule that looks at the subject of incoming messages and fires when it sees "A new incident". Have the rule run a script. I called mine "Check_For_Ticket" in this example. See the pic of my rule attached.
Sub Check_For_Ticket(MyMail As MailItem)
    On Error GoTo Proc_Error

    Dim strTicket, strSubject As String

    ' Default value in case # is not found in the subject line
    strTicket = "None"

    ' Grab the subject from the message
    strSubject = MyMail.Subject

    ' See if it has a hash symbol in it
    If InStr(1, strSubject, "#") > 0 Then

        ' Trim off leading stuff up to and including the hash symbol
        strSubject = Mid(strSubject, InStr(strSubject, "#") + 1)

        ' Now find the trailing space after the ticket number and chop it off after that
        If InStr(strSubject, " ") > 0 Then
            strTicket = Left(strSubject, InStr(strSubject, " ") - 1)
        End If
    End If
    MsgBox "Your Ticket # is: " & strTicket

Proc_Done:
    Exit Sub

Proc_Error:
    MsgBox "An error has occured in Check_For_Ticket. Error #" & Err & " - " & Err.Description
    GoTo Proc_Done
End Sub
'Of course, you would substitute whatever processing you want where the messagebox shows the ticket number.
```